# Serializer.Serialize saves ZERO bytes to my stream (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, protobuf-net

I have the following .vb code  generated from ProtoGen.exe

```
' Generated from: proto/Test.proto
Namespace axBasic
<Global.System.Serializable, Global.ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name:="Test")> _
Public Partial Class Test
    implements Global.ProtoBuf.IExtensible

    Public Sub New
    End Sub

    Private _id As UInteger
    <Global.ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired:=True, Name:="id", DataFormat:=Global.ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)> _ 
    Public Property id As UInteger
        Get 
            Return _id
        End Get

        Set(value As UInteger)
        _id = value 

        End Set
    End Property

    Private extensionObject As Global.ProtoBuf.IExtension
        Function GetExtensionObject(createIfMissing As Boolean) As Global.ProtoBuf.IExtension Implements Global.ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject
            Return Global.ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(extensionObject, createIfMissing)
        End Function
End Class

End Namespace
```

The Test.Proto file is very simple:

```
package axBasic;

message Test {
  required uint32  id = 1;
}
```

I try to generate a simple .bin file with the following code but it's always ZERO bytes

```
Dim t = New axBasic.Test With {.id = 1}
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(IO.File.Create("1.bin"), t)
```

Please have I missed a step? why isn't this working?

Comment: How are you going to close that file?  Use the *Using* statement.

Comment: I am curious why you are using .proto files.  It is fairly straight forward and easy/easier to use it directly.

Comment: @Plutonix i'm trying to get my head around the ptotobuf-net library

Comment: @HansPassant let me rewrite that with using and see

Comment: ProtoBuf can be used just like the BinaryFormatter without the ProtoGen step.  The attributes are a but different, but simpler overall, esp considering your other conversion question.

Comment: @Plutonix you are suggesting that i simply build a POCO and use the lib to serialize. that makes sense, but in my eventual use case, im receiving bytes on the wire and i will be doing mainly de-serializing of raw bytes to classes. The data structure is defined in a .proto file from another platform

Comment: @HansPassant would auto-flush=true not achieve similar?

Comment: That was what I asked: "why".  If you dont close the file, nothing (.NET, Win, File system) can know whether or not you are done writing.  `End Using` closes and disposes the underlying stream.

Comment: No, it is a FileStream, not a StreamWriter.

Comment: @MarcGravell would be nice if Serializer.Deserialize() had a simple overload that takes just bytes, not only a stream. no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero bytes is actually entirely legal in protobuf, although I would only expect that if it was all defaults (id=0 would probably do it). In reality, I suspect this is simply a case of not closing the file correctly. As noted in comments, you should use a using statement around files. In c# terms:

```
using(var file = IO.File.Create("1.bin")) {
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(file, t);
}
```

Comment: @Charles0 if you don't close files properly, you have no way of knowing how much data is still buffered. The garbage collector can release the windows handle, but it can't touch/check a managed buffer, because the collection order is non-deterministic: the buffer might have already been collected.

Comment: Noted, but in the past I usually just set auto-flush=true on my file stream, and things get written out properly.

Comment: @Charles0 did you do that this time? But: explicitly closing (better: disposing) is a very very good idea - not least, it makes the file readable to other processes

Comment: Yeah, i gueess I'll adopt the using pattern

Comment: @Charles0 to put it bluntly: that is the most important pattern in .net - you should be using using as a matter of routine

Comment: would be nice if your Serializer.Deserialize() had a simple overload that takes just bytes, not just a stream

Comment: @CharlesO serializing to a `Stream` is pretty much the canonical pattern; serializing to a `byte[]` has issues in terms of what to do if the data is larger than the buffer. You can always use a `MemoryStream` over an existing `byte[]`, of course.